# Angular2 Validate input using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I want to define quantity of symbols in my regex

```
_keyPress(ptrn: string, event: any) {
    const pattern = new RegExp(ptrn);
    const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar) && !pattern.test(value)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

html:

```
<input (keypress)="_keyPress('[a-z]{,6}', $event)">
```

But it doesn't work if I use quantity quantifier. Who can say what's going wrong?
https://plnkr.co/edit/fIVAvRJcubzD2SxZqlTY?p=preview

Comment: Try setting `0` as the minimum value - `[a-z]{0,6}`. Better with anchors to require the full string match - `^[a-z]{0,6}$`

Comment: is it comming in _keyPress function you tried to console log in the function

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew No, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `event.charCode` returns number between `97` and `122` for `a-z`. So, the `pattern.test(inputChar)` test always fails because you are trying to compare digits to alphabets. So, change `inputChar` to following:

`const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.key ? event.which : event.key);`

Also, value needs to be updated with the next key entered by user:

`const value = (event.target.value) + inputChar;`

I am assuming you are trying to restrict the user from enter any keys except `a-z` and only allowing them enter up to 6 alphabets. Therefore, the final test needs an `||` flag instead of `&&`, because the input should be allowed when both of tests pass, not just when one of them pass.

```
if (!pattern.test(inputChar) || !pattern.test(value)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
```

Here's the Plnkr [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xVgRba4nNCWZxfnSuRPa?p=preview) forked from yours.